# import org.eclipse cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I just installed Eclipse Neon PDE and try to build a simple plugin project with the "Hello World" template. Unfortunately i get many "The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved" errors straight after creating the plugin project.

This is the project with the errors in code and dependencies:
[image: Error].

I use Eclipse Neon for RCP and RAP Developers with these plugins:
[image: plugins].

I already tried cleaning the project and fiddled around with the build path but without success.

Can anyone help me with this error? Probably I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: Did you use 'New > Plug-in Project' to create this? That should have added more dependencies than you currently have. Look in the 'Problems' view and show us the errors listed there.

Comment: Yes, i used 'New->Plug-in Project' to create this. I added the 'Problem' to abobe

Comment: Yes, i used 'New->Plug-in Project' to create this. I added the 'Problem' view to the screenshot above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg is right. Also check your target platform in Windows->Target Platform->Add.
Add default setup there.
Please find more details adding target platform @ http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem in Linux. I never had to to configure the target platform in Windows though.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a number of plug-in dependencies.

You need to add at least:

```
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
 org.eclipse.core.resources
```

to your plug-in dependencies list. You will probably have to do a 'Source > Organize Imports' after adding the dependencies to update the imports.

You can always click on the red X at the left of the editor to get possible resolutions of problems - this will often tell you which dependency to add.

Comment: I tried to add the above mentioned dependencies through the 'Add' button in the Dependencies tab, but the referred dependencies aren't listed there. I'm also aware of the quick fix feature. If i try it on the mentioned error in line 18 for example do 'Fix project setup' then eclipse says 'No proposals have been found to fix the unresolvable reference to 'AbstractHandler'. Click here to manually configure the build path of project 'HelloWorld''.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your Eclipse plugin development setup. Check the target platform as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by launching the eclipse with "-clean" arguments.